# Sequences over finite fields

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

Let's we have finite field $F_q$ for some prime $q=2^M-1$.

I am looking for special sequence {$a_{i}$, $i \in {1,..,q-1}$},
($\{a_{1},...,a_{q-1}\}=F_q/\{0\}$) with the following properties:

$r_{1}=a_1$ = 2;

Let's  ${r_{s}} = \sum_{k=1}^s{a_{k}}$

then:

$\{r_{1},...,r_{q}\} =F_q$.

Thanks.

Comment: You must have $a_i=0$ for some $i$, and then you'll have $r_i=r_{i-1}$.

Comment: Correct, excluded zero

Answer (score 2):

This [paper](https://community.middlebury.edu/%7Ejschmitt/papers/HicksOllisSchmitt2018.pdf) uses the polynomial method and other techniques to study the problem.

Hicks, Ollis and Schmitt, *Distinct Partial Sums in Cyclic Groups: Polynomial Method and Constructive Approaches*

The following conjecture is stated there.

**Conjecture 1.2.** (Archdeacon, Dinitz, Mattern and Stinson) For any cyclic group $\mathbb Z_n$ and any $k-$subset $A ⊆ \mathbb Z_n\setminus\{0\}$, it is possible to find an ordering of the elements of $A$ such that no two of its partial sums are equal for $1≤i<j≤k.$